# Array só retorna um único resultado para a função, como resolver isso?

Tags: php, array, funções

Basicamente eu envio múltiplos arquivos através do formulário.

O formulário está no arquivo: cadastro_de_noticia.php

```
<form action="cadastraNoticia.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="anexo_noticia[]" type="file" multiple>
...
</form>
```

Eu recebo esses arquivos através de uma função que criei para tratar estes arquivos, porém, após o tratamento eu necessito retornar os arquivos em forma de array para então inserí-los no BD, porém só consigo receber o primeiro arquivo do array, e não todos os que enviei.
Segue o código da arquivo cadastraNoticia.php:

```
<?php
require("../lib/conexao.php");
require("../lib/preparaImagem.php");
require("../lib/preparaAnexo.php");
$imagem = Imagem\preparaImagem($_FILES['imagem_noticia'], "noticias");

// Função que recebe os arquivos do formulário, trata e devolve;
$anexo = Anexo\preparaAnexo($_FILES['anexo_noticia'], "anexos");

$titulo = $_POST['titulo_noticia'];
$conteudo = $_POST['conteudo_noticia'];

$sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO noticias (titulo, conteudo, img, anexo, data_publicacao) VALUES (:TITULO, :CONTEUDO, :IMAGEM, :ANEXO, now() ) ");
$sql->bindParam(":TITULO", $titulo);
$sql->bindParam(":CONTEUDO", $conteudo);
$sql->bindParam(":IMAGEM", $imagem);
$sql->bindParam(":ANEXO", $anexo);
$sql->execute();

if($sql){
    echo "<script>alert('Notícia cadastrada com sucesso!'); window.location.href = '../?p=noticias';</script>";
}else{
    echo "<script>alert('Falha ao cadastrar notícia.'); window.location.href = '../?p=noticias';</script>";
}
```

Segue o código da função:

```
<?php
namespace Anexo;

function preparaAnexo($anexo, $dir){

    if(!file_exists("../../assets/uploads/{$dir}")){
        mkdir('../../assets/uploads/'.$dir.'', 0777, true);
    }

    $arquivos_permitidos = ['doc', 'docx', 'ppt', 'pptx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'pdf'];
    $nomeTemp = $anexo['tmp_name'];
    $nomeDosArquivos = $anexo['name'];
    $tamanhoDosArquivos = $anexo['size'];
    $pastaDestino = "../../assets/uploads/".$dir."/";

    for($i = 0; $i < count($nomeDosArquivos); $i++):
        
        if($tamanhoDosArquivos[$i] > 0 && $tamanhoDosArquivos[$i] < 2024000){

            $extensao = explode('.', $nomeDosArquivos[$i]);
            $nomeArq = current($extensao);
            $extensao = end($extensao);
            

            if(in_array($extensao, $arquivos_permitidos)){

                if(copy($nomeTemp[$i], $pastaDestino.$nomeArq.".".$extensao)){
                   return $nomeDosArquivos[$i];
                }else{
                    echo "<script>alert('Falha ao enviar o anexo.');</script>";
                }
            }else{
                die("Tipo inválido! Não aceitamos anexo do tipo <strong>".$extensao."</strong>");
            }
        }else{
            echo "<script>alert('Não é possível enviar arquivos vazios, por favor, preencha o campo corretamente.');</script>";
        }
        
    endfor;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O *return* dentro do *if(copy...* está quebrando o ciclo de repetição e retornando apenas o nome do arquivo da primeira posição.

O que poderia ser feito é armazenar os arquivos copiados com sucesso para a posição referente em um novo array:

```
<?php
    namespace Anexo;
    
    function preparaAnexo($anexo, $dir){
    
        if(!file_exists("../../assets/uploads/{$dir}")){
            mkdir('../../assets/uploads/'.$dir.'', 0777, true);
        }
    
        $arquivos_permitidos = ['doc', 'docx', 'ppt', 'pptx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'pdf'];
        $nomeTemp = $anexo['tmp_name'];
        $nomeDosArquivos = $anexo['name'];
        $tamanhoDosArquivos = $anexo['size'];
        $pastaDestino = "../../assets/uploads/".$dir."/";
        
        $arquivosSalvos = array();
   
        for($i = 0; $i < count($nomeDosArquivos); $i++):
            
            if($tamanhoDosArquivos[$i] > 0 && $tamanhoDosArquivos[$i] < 2024000){
    
                $extensao = explode('.', $nomeDosArquivos[$i]);
                $nomeArq = current($extensao);
                $extensao = end($extensao);
                
                if(in_array($extensao, $arquivos_permitidos)){
                    if(copy($nomeTemp[$i], $pastaDestino.$nomeArq.".".$extensao)){
                       $arquivosSalvos[] = $nomeDosArquivos[$i];
                    }else{
                         $arquivosSalvos[] = null;
                    }
                }else{
                    $arquivosSalvos[] = null;
                }
            }else{
                $arquivosSalvos[] = null;
            }
            
        endfor;

     return $arquivosSalvos;

    }
```

Assim os array retornado teria o nome dos arquivos que foram salvos com sucesso e *null* para os que não foram.

Comment: Muito obrigado meu amigo, deu certinho aqui!
Como sempre, me ajudando muito. 